# regex-pcre: What imports do I need?

Tags: haskell

I installed my first Haskell package with *cabal*:

```
$ cabal install regex-pcre
```

Could someone post a simple example using pcre regexes so I can figure out what I am supposed to import?

Comment: Okay, I figured it out:

Comment: When in doubt, look at the [Hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre-0.94.4) for the package; it will usually have documentation, but at the least will list exposed modules.

Comment: @isturdy I didn't find that Hackage page at all useful, in terms of showing how to actually use the library.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out.  The module you need is Text.Regex.PCRE.  For POSIX regexes, it's Text.Regex.Posix.  Here is an example:

```
ghci>:m +Text.Regex.PCRE
ghci>"heeeee" =~ "hee|he*" :: [[String]]
Loading package array-0.4.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package bytestring-0.9.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package deepseq-1.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package containers-0.4.2.1 ... linking ... done.
Loading package transformers-0.3.0.0 ... linking ... done.
Loading package mtl-2.1.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package regex-base-0.93.2 ... linking ... done.
Loading package regex-pcre-0.94.4 ... linking ... done.
[["hee"]]

ghci>:m -Text.Regex.PCRE
ghci>:m +Text.Regex.Posix
ghci>"heeeee" =~ "hee|he*" :: [[String]]
Loading package regex-posix-0.95.2 ... linking ... done.
[["heeeee"]]
```